# currentFrame identifiers [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, identifier

I'm completely new to Flash and AS3, and I'd have thought this would be a simple question, but I've been unable to find an answer online or in the documentation. I'm trying to use addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME) and (.currentFrame) to disable a button for part of an animation sequence. While the animation sequence fades in, the Button Hand cursor is visible and people can select it before the sequence is completed. I want this button disabled for the first 213frames of the main timeline, which is when the button becomes visible.

Earlier, I was successfully able to disable a Rewind button for parts of a different movie scene using the code below with a few insignificant things changed.

```
Skip_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SkipToGoToScene);

function SkipToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Opening");
}

//Skip_btn functions

Skip_btn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, skipDisable);

function skipDisable(event:Event) {
if (this.currentFrame < 213)
{   Skip_btn.mouseEnabled = false;
} else {
Skip_btn.mouseEnabled = true;
}

if (this.currentFrame > 213) {
Skip_btn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, skipDisable);
}
}
```

The problem is that before I could just use "this.currentFrame" as the button was on the same timeline that it controlled, whereas now it's embedded in a MovieClip that is on the main timeline. What can I swap "this" for so I can reference this main timeline? Also, could someone fill me in on what the other "identifiers" are for ".currentFrame", as I'm not too sure how it works. The documentation examples ask for Movieclips such as "MyMovie_mc.currentFrame", but what if you just want to reference a main timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is on main timeline you could just use

```
this.root.getChildByName("Skip_btn").mouseEnabled = true;
```

And if you start playing animation on main timeline use

```
MovieClip(this.root).currentFrame
```

Comment: Thanks mate, MovieClip(this.root).currentFrame works a treat :)